# Object Parameters to Wcf Webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

H,

I've never worked or written a C# wcf webservice before.

The webservice method I am using has the signature as below, also written by third party who hasn't worked with wcf before:

```
public void AddOrder(Order o, DeliveryMethod dm)
```

However, is it possible to pass the Order and DeliveryMethod object directly to the service without them being in xml form first? Or does the interaction and transfer between the webservice and my website serialize when needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF supports many different bindings which allow you to decide what format to be used when calling the service. If you are using the standard `basicHttpBinding` then your service will use a SOAP endpoint which implies XML. But any case when calling a web service you need to serialize/deserialize data before sending them on the wire.

Comment: OK, thats fine, I would serialize the Order and DeliveryMethod objects. But I guess the website method also then needs to de-serialize these before use? The reason I ask is so I can check that the 3rd party is doing this.

Comment: @N00b, in order to consume a web service you usually generate a proxy client (for example in VS: Add Service Reference) and then use this proxy to call the service. Behind the scenes it will do all the serialization/deserialization depending on the binding being used so that you only have to work with objects and never manually serialize/deserialize data.

Comment: Right ok I understand, however, does this still apply on webservice side within the AddOrder method? I.e. when using DeliveryMethod dm, would the 3rd party writing this service need to deserialize what I have sent across?

Comment: @N00b, I don't understand your question. Basically you have a service and a client: the service exposes some metadata, the client builds a proxy and uses this proxy to call the service. That's it.

Comment: @Darin.. I guess what I am asking is: the client calls a webservice method providing the Order object in the request. Behind the scenes this is serialized by the proxy and sent to the webservice. When the webservice method receives it, does it first need to deserialize it to the Order object type or is this also done automatically?

Comment: @N00b, yes the web service needs to deserialize it back to an `Order` object. Remember that all the service gets from the client is a raw bytes array from the socket. Of course this deserialization is automatically done by the WCF infrastructure. You should never work at such a low level in your code. Inside the web method you will already get an `Order` object if the client properly invoked the service.